# Array.filter first of value

Tags: javascript

I have a json array based on this structure:

```
[
    {property1: "bmw", property2: value, property3: value, property4: value},
    {property1: "mercedes", property2: value, property3: value, property4: value},
    {property1: "bmw", property2: value, property3: value, property4: value},
    {property1: "nissan", property2: value, property3: value, property4: value}
]
```

How can i filter the array to find the first time a new value appears for `property1` and store it in a separate array?

I would like the array like: `["bmw", "mercedes", "nissan"]`

Comment: Can you provide an expected input & output? Does the first index count as being changed? Do you just want the first time it changes, or every time?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store unique values, you should use the JavaScript built in-object [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

The method `.add(value)` will append `value` to your set only if it doesn't already exist

```js
let carNames = new Set();
let cars= [
    { property1: "bmw" },
    { property1: "mercedes" },
    { property1: "bmw" },
    { property1: "nissan" }
];

cars.forEach(car => carNames.add(car.property1));

console.log(carNames.size);
for (let name of carNames) {
   console.log(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not quite what i wanted but i modified it a little and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array carNames, iterate over your cars, and each time the property1 of a car is not contained in carNames array, add it

```
    var cars= [
    {property1: "bmw", property2: "d", property3: "", property4: "value"},
    {property1: "mercedes", property2: "value", property3: "value", property4: "value"},
    {property1: "bmw", property2: "value", property3: "value", property4: "value"},
    {property1: "nissan", property2: "value", property3: "value", property4: "value"}
];

var carNames = [];
cars.forEach(function(car){
    if (! carNames.includes(car.property1))
        carNames.push(car.property1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure of the original data, I'd reduce the array into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) using the property as key

```js
var cars= [
    {property1: "bmw", property2: "d", property3: "", property4: "value"},
    {property1: "mercedes", property2: "value", property3: "value", property4: "value"},
    {property1: "bmw", property2: "value", property3: "value", property4: "value"},
    {property1: "nissan", property2: "value", property3: "value", property4: "value"}
];

var m = cars.reduce((map, entry) => {
 if (!map.has(entry.property1)) {
  map.set(entry.property1, entry)
 }
 return map
}, new Map())

console.log([...m.values()]);
console.log([...m.keys()]);
```

you can then extract the entries with `.values()` to get the full objects or `.keys()` to get only the unique brand names